# 2008 iMac, Ubuntu Stuck on Purple Screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, mac, grub-efi, apple

I've been struggling to get Ubuntu 18.04 to work on my [2008 iMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.8-24-inch-aluminum-early-2008-penryn-specs.html).

Grub loads. But system gets stuck on blank purple screen.

I have "nomodeset" enabled.

Ubuntu LiveCD works on same iMac. So the iMac can run Ubuntu.

Followed the steps in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mmiglier/ubuntu-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-mac-compatible-469ad33645c9) to install Ubuntu.